# Modify AD Description of Computer

Tags: powershell

I want to modify the Description field of our Computers by adding the Serial number into it.
First I exported a list of our computers:

```
$a = Read-Host "Enter Starting of Computername"
$a =  "$a*"

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like $a' -Properties IPv4Address,Description | FT Name,DNSHostName,IPv4Address,Description -A > C:\temp\Computer.csv
```

after that I copied the List and modified it to run the following script to get the Serial number of every computer.

```
$(
echo COMPUTER:PC123;wmic /NODE: PC123 bios get serialnumber;
echo COMPUTER:PC234;wmic /NODE: PC234 bios get serialnumber;
echo COMPUTER:PC345;wmic /NODE: PC345 bios get serialnumber;
) *>&1 > C:\temp\output_test.csv
```

If the Computer is in the Network I receive the result:

COMPUTER:PC123
SerialNumber

123xyz

But if the Computer is not available I've got an error of course.

At the end for me is counting to have a list with all Computers like

> COMPUTER:PC123
>
> SerialNumber
>
> 123xyz
>
> COMPUTER:PC234
>
> SerialNumber
>
> not reached

Any ideas?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

powershell has built-in cmdlets for almost any kind of activity you need so try to use them before going to cmd tools like `wmic` etc.

also use `export-csv` to export data to csv format.

variables are not expanded in single quotes so you need to use double quotes on the filter param value:

```
    Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like $a" -Properties IPv4Address,Description | Select Name,DNSHostName,IPv4Address,Description | export-csv C:\temp\Computer.csv -NoTypeInformation
    import-csv c:\temp\computer.csv | 
        ForEach-Object {
            if(Test-Connection $_.name -quiet)
            {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{ Computer = $_.name; Serialnumber = (gwmi win32_bios -ComputerName $_.name).serialnumber;Reachable=$true}

            }
            else
            {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{ Computer = $_.name; Serialnumber = $null;Reachable=$false}

            }
    } | export-csv c:\temp\output.csv -notype
```

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks. I Tried that. How can I export the result of the foreach loop into a csv file as well?

Comment: just like how we did the first export...anyway see the edit.